# cant parse xml using a KSOAP2

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, xml-parsing, ksoap2

I have connected to the asp.net Service using Ksoap2 and it connects fine, but one thing is that i get the response back in XML. Is there anyway i can get it to display in normal text.

This is the code i have used

```
public class AndroidWebService extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetHelpDeskCalls";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "GetHelpDeskCalls";
static final String URL = "https://198.125.364:8080/AndroidServices/Service1.asmx";

Button getData;
EditText userID;
TextView data;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.helpdesk);

    getData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    userID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFar);
    data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Thread nT = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            getData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                            METHOD_NAME);

                    request.addProperty("userID", userID.getText()
                            .toString());

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;

                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                    try {
                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                                URL);

                        // androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                        final String ss = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;

                        // final SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope
                        // .getResponse();

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {


                                data.setText(ss.toString());
                            }

                        });

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        data.setText("Error");
                    }
                }

            });

        }

    };
    nT.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a neat website called google, it does wonders.

since you seem to be lazy there are 3 basic xml parsing methods you can use

`SAX parser`,
`DOM parser`,
`XML pull parser`

read about xml parsing [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html)

Comment: i have tried that other wise i wouldnt be on here, and i believe i asked the wrong question anyways, i tried SAX parser but it doesnt work

Comment: what does not work about it? these methods are how you parse xml files in android

Comment: i don't know how to get the xml returned by the web service and the parser to work together, it just returns null. i've seen input source with http requests etc, but i don't know how to do this with a soap webservice, i hope this makes sense, english is not my first language, and i'm new to  general programming, 2 months experience! thanks